# wild card redirects issue giving error this webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my website I changed or better word modified the directory name ""vehicles-cars"" to ""vehicles-cars-for-sale"" when i tried to redirect using wild card redirect my old directory name to new directory name in my web hosting cpanel account. every time when i open pages from that directory i am getting error code.

This web-page has a redirect loop.

The website is php.

The problem is that that my lots of pages from old directory are indexed in googles and they are getting duplicate contents.

If I redirect single page it works perfect but there are lots of pages so I need wild card redirect to redirect whole directory .

I really need some advice what to do with this problem.

Here is `.htaccess` file code for redirect thanks

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$

RewriteRule ^vehicles\-cars\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/vehicles\-cars\-for\-sale\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

i have other wilcard redirect of whole directory with same code and its working perfect here is the code in .htaccss file which is same as above and working perfect for this directory

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^adsbuz\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.adsbuz\.com$
RewriteRule ^autos\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/adsbuz\.com\/vehicles\-cars\-for\-sale\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

so i dont understand whats wrong with the above code 
please i really need some expert advice thanks again

Answer (score 0):

`^vehicles\-cars/?(.*)$` will match: `/vehicles-cars-for-sale/` causing your loop.

I'd start by removing the optional operator for the trailing /:

`RewriteRule ^vehicles\-cars/(.*)$ ....`

and add another one to deal with the one URL that wouldn't match:

`RewriteRule ^vehicles\-cars$ ...`

This -should- work; I haven't tested it:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$

RewriteRule ^vehicles\-cars/(.*)$ http://example\.com\/vehicles\-cars\-for\-sale/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^vehicles\-cars$ http://example\.com\/vehicles\-cars\-for\-sale/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: sir i really appreciate your resposec is what that you exactly recomend   see the code below please

Comment: I uh, don't see any code :o

Comment: sir i really appreciate your respective response   but here you are recommending one with /  and another out with out / if you don't mind and have time please do me a favor write the whole .htaccess code to redirect my directory as above thanks i hope you don't mind

Comment: Politeness goes a long way ;)

Comment: sir i am really sorry for that

Comment: It was a compliment lol

Comment: sir i don't have words to say thank you solved my big problem thanks  a lot its working perfect now. i was searching and trying different codes but was not working i don't no how it directs but its working and thats i think  for time being enough for me instead of thinking why the other one was not working thanks again